# Install the Jmeter certificate in iOS

Tags: ios, jmeter, certificate

How to download and install the Jmeter certificate in iOS 12?
I want to test an iOS application with Jmeter and couldn't find anywhere online.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue , the solution is attach the certificate file (crt) on email (google account) from laptop and then open your gmail account in safari web-browser(not in gmail app), that will automatically install the profile , check in settings-->general-->Profiles.

Comment: Oh thanks for the idea. Actually, I did the same in another way. After attaching the crt file in Gmail, I opened the same in the Apple mail app in my mobile. Then it asked to install. Afte that, u can trust the certificate from the settings app in the mobile again.

Comment: This will help iOS Users - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/46607/install-root-ca-certificate-in-mobile-to-use-jmeter-script-recorder-but-showing